# In Multiplayer Battlefield Bad Company 2, what is hardcore mode?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

I see this listed on the server filters but I don't know what it is.

In Multiplayer Battlefield Bad Company 2, what is hardcore mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is similar to call of duty's hardcore mode. Hardcore mode was added to further the sense of realism in the game.

In hardcore mode there is no HUD so you cant check how much ammo you have remaining etc, the amount of damage you can sustain is reduced so you'll be dead within a couple of shots, but watch out for those snipers! You will die within one shot from a sniper rifle. Finally there will be no kill cam so you can't see how you died.

I hope this info helps.

Answer (score 3):

Differences between casual and hardcore:

- in casual you have HUD (crosshair, ammo info, minimap etc.), in HC you don't;
- in casual you have killcam, in HC no, so snipers are lot more of problem;
- in casual you start with 200 of health, in HC with only 80;
- in casual you regain health with time, in HC you can only regain health with medkit;
- in casual there are no TKs, in HC there's -25 points for hurting teammate, -100 for TK;
- in casual re-spawn wait is usually short, in HC it's more like 15s; *(that has lot of impact in rush)*
- on some HC servers you have no 3rd person view for vehicles;